# tengo un proyecto con varias app y me esta dando «ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist»

Tags: python, django, postgresql

tengo un proyecto con varias app y me esta dando este error

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_user" does not exist

ya he probado poniendo

> python manage.py migrate
>
> python manage.py makemigrate

Me dice que no hay cambios y, al final, me sigue dando el mismo error incluso probé migrando app por app por ejemplo

> python manage.py migrate usuario

y, nada, me sigue el mismo error...he seguido todo lo que han puesto y nada me resuelve el problema

Comment: ¿Conectándote directo a la base de datos con el mismo usuario se puede acceder (hacer select) en esa tabla (auth_user)?

Answer (score 1):

Seria bueno que especificaras que version de django estas usando siempre, y a que gestor de base de datos te estas conectando, si estas en un ambiente de prueba y te podes dar el lujo de borrar la base de datos, te recomiendo borrar la base de datos y volverla a generarla con `python manage migrate` Si aun asi da error entonces es alguna configuracion podria ser el orden de tus installed apps si alguno de tus modelos en alguna de tus apps se relaciona con el modelo User entonces 'django.contrib.admin' debe estar antes que esas apps.

Otra opcion probando las migraciones por app es correr primero:

```
python manage.py migrate auth
```

y despues:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, ese error es dado por no incluir la aplicación `'django.contrib.auth'` en tu archivo `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth'
    ...
)
```